# Eclipse - Publishing at Project Level

Tags: eclipse, ide, spring-tool-suite

I have 2 projects in eclipse:

- Project A
- Project B

Project A is a Java REST API that I would like to be automatically published when anything changes.

Project B is the front end, I have a build process that converts TypeScript e.t.c into the relevant JavaScript. I write the build folder directly into it's Tomcat Location - I don't want it to be in my project.

With this is mind, is there a way for me to configure Eclipse so that:

- Project A has the Automatic Publishing Option
- Project B never gets Automatically published.

I know I can either enable/disable automatic publishing globally but I would like to do it on a project specific basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in Eclipse. But I've been using the built in support for Gulp tasks which has made things easier - I can configure whether or not to refresh projects when a task is ran.